# Horizontal scroll on panoramic image with HTML buttons using jquery

Tags: jquery, scroll, horizontal-scrolling

Looking for a solution for a horizontal scroll on a large panoramic image (e.g. a timeline).

I can currently scroll using scroll/two-finger touchpad, but I'd like to be able to scroll using a mouse-click.

I drew up a JSFiddle using elements from StackOverflow but I can't get this to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
 <div class="buttons">
  <button id="left">LEFT</button>
  <button id="right">RIGHT</button>
 </div>
 <div class="inner">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/550x300">
 </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#right').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#inner').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('#left').click(function() {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('#inner').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

CSS:

```
.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 550px;
  top: 25px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/phkst96c/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) There's no `#inner` in the HTML, it's a class `.inner`.

2) `event` would be `undefined` since you forgot to pass it to the function.

```
$('#right').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.outer').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

3) `.inner` will not `overflow` cause its width equals the image's width. What you want is scrolling `.outer`.

```js
$('#right').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.outer').animate({
    scrollLeft: "+=200px"
  }, "slow");
});

 $('#left').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.outer').animate({
    scrollLeft: "-=200px"
  }, "slow");
});
```

```css
.buttons {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
}

.outer {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: scroll;
}

.inner {
  width: 550px;
  top: 25px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
<div class="buttons">
<button id="left">LEFT</button>
<button id="right">RIGHT</button>
</div>
<div class="inner">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/550x300">
</div>
</div>
```